# Need to pass currency code in geoplugin class as variable

Tags: php, fix-my-code

I am making a module displaying google map and retrieving the data in the marker info box from database. It is a hotel booking website. The currency stored in the database is Hotel's default currency while my goal is to show currency according to user's location.

I am using geoplugin class but it stops working when I try to pass variable or try to set variable in the class. I fetched the currency code from the database and tried to pass as variable to set it as base currency but it didn't work.

```
$curr = "USD"; // say "USD" is fetched from database

class geoPlugin {

  public $curr;
  //the geoPlugin server
  var $host = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip={IP}&base_currency={CURRENCY}';


  //the default base currency
  var $currency = $curr;
  or $currency = $this->curr;
```

I also tried to set the variable inside the class

```
class geoPlugin {

  var $host = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip={IP}&base_currency={CURRENCY}';
  public $curren;

  public function setVariableOne($curr) {
  $this->$curren = $curr;
}

//the default base currency
var $currency = $curren;
and in index file

$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->setVariableOne('USD');
```

Comment: first, did you get any error?

Comment: Yes there was an error. Class is not accepting variable value for $currency.

Answer (score 2):

First of all change

```
$this->$curren = $curr;
```

To

```
$this->curren = $curr;
```

And add default to property just after class opening tag (not in method)

```
public $curr = 'USD';
```

Regards

EDIT1 :

```
class geoPlugin {

    public $curren;

    public function setVariableOne($curr) 
    {
        $this->curren = $curr;
    }
}
```

thats work try if this code not work for you plz give us some hints by using errrors ; )

edit2:

do this and tell me if is working for you ( save it to new file ).

```
class geoPlugin {

    public $curren = 'USD';

    public function setVariableOne($curr) 
    {
        $this->curren = $curr;
    }

    public function getVariableOne()
    {
        return $this->curren;
    }
}

$geo = new geoPlugin();
var_dump( $geo->getVariableOne() ); // return 'USD' string
$geo->setsetVariableOne('EUR');
var_dump( $geo->getVariableOne() ); // return 'EUR' string
```

if this give you a blank page, please set error_reporting(-1) and then tell me the error code.

pastebin with geoplugin.class.php and it's working as it should be: http://pastebin.com/FWkYVsjg

Comment: Thanks for indicating the typo. My problem is, I need to pass the default currency in variable as it is coming from database.
If I try to pass a variable in $currency, the code stops working. I also tried to set a variable just after class opening tag and pass to $currency.

Comment: I did the same. The screen goes blank whenever I try to pass a variable to $currency  (like: var $currency = $curren; )

Comment: Same. When I tried to pass var $currency = $curren; , I got following error.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in .....

Comment: you can not do `var $currency = $curren` in class out of the method. Just paste my edit into your new php file and look what i saying about.

Comment: I have tried your code but the class is taking USD as default in any case. Please find the code here [link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=1AE2FD23AEB92B7E!489)

Comment: I need to convert prices coming from database into local currency. You can see currency conversion factor is [currencyConverter] => 3.6731 while  currency is set to [currency] => EUR. 

Please try public $currency = 'EUR'; on line 31 of your code. I need to pass dynamic value of $currency from database.